# How to propagate default values

Tags: python

Support I have defined some functions, e.g. (very simplified example)

```
def f1(a, b, arg='something'):
   ...
def f2(c, arg='else'):
   ...
```

Then I call use them as:

```
def f(a, b, c):
   return f1(a, b) + f2(c)
```

Since this is very commonly used, but I want to have `f1` and `f2` defined separately so that it is possible to call just one.

I want to have the possibility when calling `f` to call `f1` and `f2` with different default arguments, so I can do:

```
def f(a, b, c, arg1='something', arg2='else'):
   return f1(a, b, arg1) + f2(c, arg2)
```

This is not very maitanable (I have many more functions than 2 and many more arguments), since when I update one function I need to update `f`.
One options would be to use `None` as default values and then change them inside the body of the functions, e.g.

```
def f1(a, b, arg=None):
   arg = arg or 'something'
   ...
```

but this hides the real value of the default argument from the signature.
In addition this doesn't solve all my problems since if I add one new argument to `f1` I have to change the signature of `f` and also its implementation...

Comment: You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to abstract individual arguments away.  still, it seems like your issue is not default arguments as much as your encapsulation mechanism.  I think you should ask a question about what you're trying to do calling `f1` and `f2` from `f`... you say there actually many functions and arguments.  I think there's an elegant pattern to address this but I am not sure waht it is becuse I'm not entirely sure what you're areally trying to do.  https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: You either have clear function headers and maintenance issues or you use `*args` and `**kwargs` in `f` but you muddle the arguments. It's a choice between static definitions and dynamic delegation, you can't have both.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting to the point where object oriented programming can help you. You could rewrite your functions as a class:

```
class FFuncs:
        def __init__(self, a, b, c, arg1="foo", arg2="bar"):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
            self.arg1 = arg1
            self.arg2 = arg2
        def f1(self):
          return str(self.a + self.b) + self.arg1
        def f2(self):
          return str(self.c) + self.arg2
        def f(self):
          return self.f1() + self.f2()

FFuncs(2, 3, 5, arg1=" Foos and ", arg2=" Spam").f()
# Returns "5 Foos and 5 Spam"
```

Now you always have access to the default values of your kwargs before each execution. And as mentioned in the comments, if you need an especially flexible call signature for any given method of your class, you can still abstract away with `*args, **kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function!

```
def f(a, b, c, *args):
   if len(args)==2:
      return(f1(a, b, args[0]) + f2(c, args[1]))
   else:
      return(f1(a, b, None) + f2(c, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def f1(a, b, arg='something', **kwargs):
   pass
def f2(c, arg='else', **kwargs):
   pass
def f(a, b, c, arg1='something', arg2='else'):
   kwargs = locals()
   return f1(**kwargs) + f2(**kwargs)
```

If you want something from both worlds namely dynamic delegation and static definitions this is the most simple solution but it's not ideal:

- you have to add `**kwargs` to functions so they don't fail when too many arguments are passed;
- you will get logical errors easily on argument renames, e.g. rename `c` in `f2` to `b`.

If you have many `fn` functions the `return` line may end up like this:

```
return sum(f(**kwargs) for f in (f1, f2, ..., fn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use None (or sentinel, if None is actually a meaningful value) as a default value and then set the "real" default value inside the function.

**Example**

```
def f1(a, b, arg=None):
    arg = arg or 'something'
    ...
def f2(c, arg=None):
    arg = arg or 'else'
    ...

def f(a, b, c, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    return f1(a, b, arg1) + f2(c, arg2)
```

This way, if a parametr is not specified, the default value will propagate up the calling tree.